# Apple LLVM compiler -- use pragmas to inhibit all warnings for a portion of a file?

Tags: iphone, xcode, warnings, llvm, pragma

I need inhibit warnings for part of one of my source files.  This is what I have.  It's not working.

```
 #pragma GCC diagnostic push
 #pragma GCC "-w"  // also tried "-Wall"

     // code that generates warnings here

 #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Warnings exist for a reason, perhaps you should investigate why the warnings are happening and suppressing them by fixing them.

Comment: There are good reasons why the code needs to stay.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable individual warnings using the format:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwarning-to-disable"
```

Except, that doesn't work for `"-Wall"`, only for individual warnings.  I would recommend only disabling the particular warning you're experiencing, and only if it's in source files over which you've no control.  If it's in your code, you should seriously consider fixing the warnings in the proper way.

Edit: See [Section 3.8, Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), in the [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/index.html).

Edit 2: Ah, didn't realize that isn't a comprehensive list.  There doesn't appear to be any documentation containing a comprehensive list, but you can always check the source.  Poking around the clang source, it looks like [include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticGroups.td](https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticGroups.td?view=markup) lists a whole bunch of them.

Comment: OK, how do I find out which diagnostic controls my particular warning?  (In this case I can't say what is as the specific warning is still under NDA.)

Comment: Yeah, I've read that like a zillion times; my specific warning is not mentioned.  I need to turn them all off, like R2 did with the trash compactors in the Death Star :)

Answer (score 0):

If using XCode, you can go to the build log and expand the compiler output and it will tell you the warning name to use in the pragma